# Why 400 response status code when send POST?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, post, python-requests

I want to parse product data from this [page](https://www.eprice.it/sa/?qs=6970995781939), but with `requests.get` it is not work. So I inspected page networks and found intereste link:

[image]

I tried to send post request to this link with correct form data, but in response i got only `{"message":"Expecting value (near 1:1)","status":400}`

How can I get correct product data from this [page](https://www.eprice.it/sa/?qs=6970995781939)?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": '*/*',
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'cgrd9wlxe4-dsn.algolia.net',
    'Origin': 'https://www.eprice.it',
    'Referer': "https://www.eprice.it/",
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": 'empty',
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-ch-ua': "Not A;Brand",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": '?0',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
}
form_data = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "indexName": "prd_products_suggest",
            "params": {
                "highlightPreTag": "<strong>",
                "highlightPostTag": "</strong>",
                "query": 6970995781939,
                "hitsPerPage": 36,
                "clickAnalytics": 1,
                "analyticsTags": ["main", "desktop"],
                "ruleContexts": ["ovr", "desktop", "t1"],
                "facetingAfterDistinct": 1,
                "getRankingInfo": 1,
                "page": 0,
                "maxValuesPerFacet": 10,
                "facets": ["manufacturer", "offer.price", "scegliPer", "offer.shopType",
                           "reviews.avgRatingInt",
                           "navigation.lvl0,navigation.lvl1,navigation.lvl2,navigation.lvl3"],
                "tagFilters": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "indexName": "prd_products_suggest_b",
            "params": {
                "query": 6970995781939,
                "hitsPerPage": 10,
                "clickAnalytics": 1,
                "analyticsTags": ["car_offerte_oggi", "desktop"],
                "ruleContexts": ["ovr", "car_offerte_oggi", "desktop"],
                "getRankingInfo": 1,
                "page": 0,
                "maxValuesPerFacet": 10,
                "minProximity": 2,
                "facetFilters": [],
                "facets": ["manufacturer", "offer.price", "scegliPer", "offer.shopType", "reviews.avgRatingInt",
                           "navigation.lvl0,navigation.lvl1,navigation.lvl2,navigation.lvl3"],
                "tagFilters": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
response = requests.post(
    url="https://cgrd9wlxe4-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?"
        "x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.11.0)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)&"
        "x-algolia-api-key=e9c9895532cb88b620f96f3e6617c00f&"
        "x-algolia-application-id=CGRD9WLXE4",
    headers=headers,
    data=form_data
)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia is a hosted search API, a retail company can index their product list into Algolia and then integrate their front-end to it to query for products to display to customers.

When you're inspecting the page networks, you're seeing the calls out to this search API that are formed by the owner of the website, the retail company, likely using the client you can download from Algolia directly.

I'm not sure why the form-data isn't working, if you download the client in Python, you will find their own example of how to integrate to it. But, the point of the context above is that the hosted Search API takes requests in different ways, so you can take the source message you have, set the **Content-Type** header to **'application-json'** and you'll get a response.

[PostMan Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7trQ.png)

The full API documentation - https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#search-index-post